# Check if pathname is dynamic route and redirect user in next js

Tags: redirect, next.js, routes, dynamic, path

Hello I use next js for my website and I try to redirect users who do not have access to a dynamic route.
for example if user want to go in /user/[id] and user is not log I want to redirect user to /
For example I do this :

```
    if (pathname === "/profil") {
         router.push("/");
    }
```

but I want to check if pathname is dynamic route. for example I have this route /user/[id] (id is uuid). I try to do this :

`if (pathname === "/user/[id]")`
`if (pathname === "/user/*")`
`if (pathname === "/user/:path*")`

but all this method not work

If you have a solution, I thank you !